# Does Eclipse IDE support Maven configs from .mvn folder like jvm.config per project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Maven project in Eclipse IDE. In the root of this maven project there is `.mvn` folder with `jvm.config` file (supported in Maven 3.3.1+). This file contains SSL truststore and password

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:/certificates/cert.jks"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=***
```

Certificate exists in the mentioned directory. I have settings.xml file in my `userhome/.m2` folder. Eclipse configured to use external Maven installation (excluding dependency resolution, because Eclipse IDE uses embedded Maven for that forcibly). Everything has been configured properly.

1. When I run `mvn clean package` from command line, then it works fine - all dependencies are downloaded from company Nexus repo and remote repositories.
2. If I import certificate into the installed JDK, then again it works. (assume `.mvn` is missing in the project root)
3. If I import certificate into Eclipse JDK plugin, then it works. (assume `.mvn` is missing in the project root)
4. If I provide `trustStore` and password in command line like below, then again it works. (assume `.mvn` is missing in the project root)

```
mvn -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:/certificates/cert.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=*** clean package
```

4. If I import this Maven project into IntelliJ IDEA, then again it works. (with `.mvn` folder and `jvm.config` file)

I have many workarounds, but want to know exactly about `.mvn` with nested configs. How to configure Eclipse IDE (or Eclipse Maven plugin) to use that `.mvn` folder with all nested configs  for successful dependency resolution?

Tested this with

- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components); Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0); Build id: 20210910-1417.
- IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1 (Community Edition); Build #IC-213.6461.79, built on December 28, 2021; Runtime version: 11.0.13+7-b1751.21 amd64; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- jdk8u312-b07 (from Eclipse Temurin)
- jdk-17.0.1 (from Oracle)
- apache-maven-3.8.3
- apache-maven-3.8.1
- Window 10, x64

Comment: As far as I know. No. The question is why does Maven needs a truststore explicit?

Comment: @khmarbaise if I understand you correctly, in our infrastructure we have our own Nexus repository with ssl. By default the jdk doesn't trust it, so we need to provide this certificate to the jdk somehow. Certificate import into cacert of jdk works fine. But this requires administrator rights, which are limited. So I can't install the jdk and I can't import the certificate. I can only manage my env as a disenfranchised user.

Comment: Hm..sounds strange. Don't getting a working access to your repository.. makes no sense. If you need a special certificate it should be offered by the it department to get you on working...I could understand having credentials for a repository manager but using a different certificate ... Hm.. yes I know TLS but that can be handled different but a different story. I would let that done once by an admin ...

Comment: Thank you. That was the last option which I was going to try. Seems now it's right time to talk to DevOps.

Comment: Yes I would do so..otherwise your life becomes not easy... That should be done once.. afterwards you can remove those supplemental configurations.

Answer (score 1):

It may help you despite not answering the question directly: if your IT has distributed the certificates on your windows computer but Java does not see them and forces you to use a specific jks file, an alternative may be to define this env variable:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
```

if your windows is configured with the certs, it will allow Java to access it without a specific aditional file.